# ElasticSearch how to convert not nested filter to query

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I have the below elastic search query in filter format which is in working fine.  However, i would like to convert this to Query format instead of filter.  Can anyone please help me out here.  "timings" is nested.

```
{
  "not": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "timings",
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "filter": {
            "missing": {
              "field": "timings.packages"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

my data has sometime packages empty. i would like to filter out records whose packages are empty.

```
timings{
  packages:[]
}
timings{
 packages:["2","4","6"]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of taking documents where `timings.packages` is `not` `missing`, you can take documents where `timings.packages` actually contains values.

That can be achieved with a `range` query taking on positive values like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "timings",
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "timings.packages": {
                "gt": 0
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I'm leaving the above query as it might help people with numbers in arrays. Another way of doing it which would work for both numbers and strings, would be to check the length oh the array via a [`script` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-filter.html), like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "timings",
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "filter": {
            "script": {
              "script": "doc['timings.packages'].size() > 0"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My packages values are strings. I edited the question to represent strings.  I want to filter out the records whose packages are empty.

Comment: I've added another way of doing it.